# Problem using HTML file as template for other HTML files using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to complete an exercise. In the exercise you create four files: index.html, home.html, about.html, and contact.html. Using jQuery's .load function, you are supposed to be able to use index.html as a template and load the other files within it (still seeing the index.html nav bar). Instead what is happening is the other html files appear to completely replace index.html in the browser. I can't figure out why. I am following the exercise instructions.

Here is the code:

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Multi-Page Site & Template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <a href="home.html">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html">About</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <h1>Index Page</h1>
        Here is where the Index Page is.
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
        u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#content").load("home.html");
                $("nav a").click(function() {
                    var href = $(this).attr("href");
                    $("#content").load(href);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

home.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <p>
            This is the home page. All content has been edited for brevity.
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

about.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>About Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>About Page</h1>
        <h2>Things to know about the About Page</h2>
        <ol>
            <li>It's named About Page</li>
            <li>It has no styling</li>
            <li>It's very short</li>
        </ol>
    </body>
    </html>
```

contact.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Contact Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Contact Page</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Billy</td>
                <td>Blazer</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The exercise said the **return false** was supposed to prevent the other pages from replacing index.html. Why does that not work, or what else is wrong with the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to below code:
In this way type="type/html" is changed to type="text/html"

```
$(function() {
     $("nav a").click(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#content").html('<object type="text/html" data="'+ href +'">        
         </object>');
        return false;
      });
  });
```

Comment: You should explain why the original didn't work, what you did different, and why yours works. "Copy/paste this" is not very useful.

Comment: In my answer type="type/html" is changed to type="text/html"

Comment: You should edit your question to add that info. Comments can get deleted easily.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I add it.

Comment: You say you updated `type="type/html"` but I don't see that anywhere in the original code so it seems added, not updated. I don't see any `<object></object>` in the original code either so your explanation looks a bit off. Seems like you added stuff and didn't mention any of it.

Comment: I appreciate the help elham, but can you tell me why the original code doesn't work, and why it is necessary to add an <object> element in order for it to work?

Comment: Your welcome . If you want to use 'load' please visit this page for more information